# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links() (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\mieaceh\resources\views\shop.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to paginate my categories `shop.blade.php` but I get this error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::links()
> (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\mieaceh\resources\views\shop.blade.php)

Here is my MenuController.blade.php

```
if (request()->category) {
  $menu = Menu::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
    $query->where('slug', request()->category);
  });

  $categories = Category::all();
  $categoryName = $categories->where('slug', request()->category)->first()->name;
} else {
  $menu = Menu::inRandomOrder()->take(10)->paginate(8);
  $categories = Category::all();
  $categoryName = 'Featured';
}

return view('shop')->with([
        'menu' => $menu,
        'categories' => $categories,
        'categoryName' => $categoryName,
]);
```

and my `shop.blade.php`

```
<div class="category text-center">
@foreach($categories as $category)
<a href="{{ route('menu.index', ['category' => $category->slug]) }}">
    <div class="card-category" style="width: 10rem; height: 4rem;">
        {{ $category->name }}
    </div>
</a>
@endforeach
```

```
{{ $menu->links() }}
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, if you have a `request()->category`, then you're not adding the paginate to the `$menu` query. Just add it

```
 $menu = Menu::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
        $query->where('slug', request()->category);
    })->paginate(8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `pagiante()` method on your menu query:

```
$menu = Menu::with('categories')->whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
            $query->where('slug', request()->category);
        })->paginate(8);
```

The way you did your query, you were returning `QueryBuilder` class, which has no `links()` method (pagination). This way you will return collection of data which you will be able to paginate.